# Reading multiple CANbus outputs with one controller

Tags: can, canopen

my encoder has a CAN communication interface. I need 4 encoders for my application. However, my controller only has 1 CAN communication interface.

Assuming, the encoder has different CAN ID, will it be possible to read out all 4 encoder values by soldering the 4 CAN_H_{1,2,3,4} and CAN_L_{1,2,3,4} wires of my encoders to one CAN_H and CAN_L, respectively?

---

Planned circuit:[image]

Comment: CAN is a bus for connecting multiple pieces of equipment together. I'd say yes but you need to provide the type and model, preferably a link to manuals, of the CAN controller and CAN encoders. You must also understand how to wire a CAN bus properly with terminations.

Comment: Ah...in the circuit 120 ohm between CAN_L and CAN_H is missing...

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can, that's why the CAN network is used on those encoders. But, you don't solder anything there, you buy a Y-splitter and prefabricated cables of specified lengths. Many different manufacturers do sell this cables. Read the manual of encoder and PLC carefully.